# Cannot install Ubuntu 17.10 though USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb

Thank you ahead of time for your help. I am having issues installing through a USB. At the grub menu, I can choose either "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" and both options lead me to a black screen. I have waited quite some time (15 min) before considering each option a failure. I used two SBs (SanDisk Cruzer U 8 GB and PNY 32 GB) both with an ISO of Ubuntu 17.10 64bit formatted to FAT32 bu Rufus. My system is an 8GB, Core i3 6th gen, with 3 GTX 1080ti and one 960. I am looking to use this build for PyCuda.

Comment: I think it will help you to boot with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. Then you get basic graphics, and you can install Ubuntu. The next step is to install a proprietary nvidia driver for your graphics cards.